# "Property ID 200 and value ID 2714985994 is not a valid combination for this listing"

Tags: codeigniter, etsy

I am having troubles deleting variations of a listing. I am sending a DELETE request to /listings/123456789/variations/200?value=2714985994 (where 200 is the property_id and 2714985994 is the value_id), but the response is:
"Property ID 200 and value ID 2714985994 is not a valid combination for this listing"

Does anybody have any idea how to delete a variation?

Answer (score 0):

/listings/123456789/variations/200?value=2714985994

This you provide value as integer but ETSY documents allow string value

For example 200 is property_id is color and value is Black

Your url like this
/listings/123456789/variations/200?value=Black